# how to single-step code on-target with no jtag, breakpoints, simulator, emulator

Tags: c, assembly, arm, gdb, embedded

Let's say you have a pointer to function whose source you do not have and which is "untrusted" because it *might* read/write to disallowed memory region.

Before it executes each assembly instruction, you want to verify that it doesn't access disallowed memory regions.

The OS is (almost) bare-metal i.e. a custom RTOS (so no Linux or QNX).

This is for a functionality that needs to be enabled not only during development but during normal runtime.

Ideally, it'd run something like this:

```
void (*fptr)(int);
fptr = &someFunction; // untrusted, don't have source
// enable interrupts for each assembly instruction
_EN_INT();
// call the function
fptr();
// everytime the PC increments, some other code runs which verifies that if any load/stores are executed, it doesn't access some disallowed memory range

// disable interrupts for each assembly instruction
_DIS_INT();
```

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to call that function and pause execution after every assembly instruction?

Comment: How about setting a breakpoint at the start of the function, and then *step* through the instructions, one by one?

Comment: If possible, run your code in a simulator / emulator that allows this.  e.g. `qemu` has a remote-GDB interface.  You can use that to single-step *anything* transparently to the code running in the virtual environment.  (e.g. you can even single-step early-boot code)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I should've clarified I meant without breakpoints.

Comment: @PeterCordes it has to be in normal runtime environment

Comment: Give this task to whomever suggested a hardware design with no jtag:(

Comment: @MartinJames it's not that we don't have a JTAG ... this is for a feature that needs to be enabled at normal runtime i.e. not only during development

Comment: You pretty much ruled out everything, what's left, magic? Hardware breakpoints not allowed either?

Comment: @Jester can anything be enabled by ARM assembly calls?

Comment: Possibly setting a timer with sufficiently short interval so it's guaranteed to fire after each instruction?

Comment: What debugging support does your RTOS have?  How do you want to trigger single-stepping, and how do you want to see the results?  (i.e. with a debugger running under your RTOS, or with a remote GDB?)

Comment: You say "a function".  Is this function one that's called normally, and you want to be *able* to single-step it, but also to let it run normally at full speed?

Comment: @PeterCordes no it doesn't have to run at full speed. The idea is that it's an untrusted function whose memory accesses we want to verify; I'll update the question.

Comment: Is the code not writable? Just insert an instruction that returns control to you after an instruction. Will not work with code that checks itself.

Comment: @Jester it is an option, I guess, to modify the `.obj` before flashed onto the target but it'd be better if there was a solution that didn't require modifying the untrusted `.obj`

Comment: @Jester oh wait I see what you mean: load it from flash into RAM and do the insertion and execution, right?

Comment: If it's in flash then that qualifies as "not writable", especially with arm code that uses literal pools. Which is also why it won't be trivial to copy it to ram and have it still work. I'd say look into hardware breakpoint support of your OS.

Comment: @Jester why can't I copy it into RAM?

Comment: I'm not sure if a continual interrupt will work?  If you interrupt-return, will the hardware execute one instruction before interrupting again?

Comment: I suppose you could copy the whole thing and that should work for pc relative addresses. I was thinking of copying one instruction at a time, duh.

Comment: Do you have an MMU or MPU?

Comment: @kkrambo I'm using cortex [MK20DX256VLH7](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/K20P32M50SF0RM.pdf?fasp=1&WT_TYPE=Reference%20Manuals&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation&fileExt=.pdf) which does mention MPU! (3.3.6.2)

Comment: Do you have room in your flash to include an ARM emulator/interpreter?  When you want to call an untrusted function, instead of running its machine code natively, run it in an emulated interpreted sandbox.  That will probably be faster than single-stepping it, but does require a LOT of code-size.  But if this function is going to be in your flash ROM, maybe you should just audit the asm so you can trust it, or rewrite it yourself...  If it's truly malicious, probably it could run privileged instructions other than memory access to take over your system.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes the ARM emulator/interpreter sounds exactly like what I want. Is there a free one?

Comment: web browsers running plugins usually resolve this by sandboxing them somehow (never checked particular details, maybe into separate process and let the OS protection handle that?). While you mention custom RTOS, you mention also ARM, so it's HW possible to create protected sandbox (like linux), although you will probably lose RT feature at the moment of the supervising sandbox setup and running the untrusted code. That said stepping over untrusted code will break RT probably too.

Comment: @Ped7g I'm not worried about real-time during this code execution; I can preempt it if necessary to limit it to a deterministic time-slice

Comment: @PeterCordes regarding auditing: in theory, that sounds like the best solution. Along with the ARM emulator/interpreter sandbox, we will explore both of them. The wildcard is how expensive either of these will be.

Comment: @Ped7g do you have an interpreter in mind?

Comment: Then maybe take a look how security is done in webbrowsers providing old NPAPI plugin API (like flash, silverlight, and all those things which were vulnerable before the sandboxes become strong enough). Also you may take a look for some VM like qemu (has ARM emulation too). In both cases I'm afraid those things will rely a lot on *NIX infrastructure, so they may turn out to be hard to run on your custom RTOS. Patching them to so-so-run partially providing only limited/required functionality may be still easier than writing your own emulator.

Comment: Plus most of it is GPL I guess, so it may be not suitable for your use case, if you can't release GPLed sources.

Comment: @Ped7g that sounds WAY more work than (1) copying code to RAM (2) inserting custom code between each assembly statement as @ Jester suggested

Comment: sure... WAY more. Then again doing Jester suggestions 100% correctly to avoid any side effects or breakage will take quite some effort. If you would specify what is the API/limits of untrusted code, maybe you are in position to put lot of constraints over it, so limited functionality with breakage in any other case is OK for your case, if the trust is important (sounds so), then the untrusted module provider has simply cope with the draconic environment and fix their code to work with your interpreted quirk in place.

Comment: Also in some cases the external parties are provided only with some kind of VM machine, like JavaScript with limited environment API, and they can't actually run anything native or access any native memory/device directly, they have to live with what they got from the main part vendor. Then as long as your sandbox/vm is simple enough and bug free, it may be not possible to break out. For best security usually all these are combined (VM running in separate process in separate chroot with limited file system, etc...), so even breaking into one layer does not provide attacker with full native.

Comment: Mind you, the trust is extremely difficult and expensive these days. Some very limited BSD installation with minimal services, probably hardened through TPM validation, digital signing, and using mostly read-only devices for code, running on HW board which is not connected outside in any way (especially not ethernet, WiFi, bluetooth, or mobile broadband) ... has some chance to be trusted/secure. Change any of it, and it's probably not worth the trust, may be extremely expensive to break, but most of the modern systems have enough backdoors/bugs. Things like IoT are basically insane idea (IMO).

Comment: If the reason for "no breakpoints" is that you think cannot set them: The chip you are using is a Cortex M4 CPU. This CPU has as special unit which allows you to place up to 3 "BKPT" instructions into the Flash memory. These 3 Flash words are read as "BKPT" regardless of what is really stored in the Flash. This is used to set breakpoints in Flash.

Comment: @MartinRosenau and what happens when execution hits those breakpoints? From [the doc](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABHCHGB.html), it doesn't say whether you NEED an external debugger to resume execution. I need the processor itself using C/C++ code to choose to resume execution.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan what issue does that help me with?

Comment: Simply grab the binary of the function, translate to assembler and see what it does? If the function is present in your executable, you don't need the source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The OS is (almost) bare-metal i.e. a custom RTOS (so no Linux or QNX).

My answer assumes that you can modify the "OS" the way you need it...

> Cortex MK20DX256VLH7

This seems to be a Cortex M4 CPU.

> how to single-step code on-target with no jtag, breakpoints
>
> From the doc, it doesn't say whether you NEED an external debugger to resume execution.

If the CPU is really stopped, you'll definitely need an external signal (e.g. from a debugger).

However most CPUs support software debugging. This means that an interrupt service routine is executed whenever a breakpoint is hit. To continue execution you simply return from the interrupt service routine.

I don't know about the Cortex M4 but for the Cortex M3 you'll have to set some special registers to enable that feature. Whenever a "BKPT" instruction is hit then interrupt #12 (*) is executed.

For code in RAM you simply write an BKPT instruction (0xBExx, e.g. 0xBEBE) to the address where you want to set your breakpoint. (Before writing you read out the value to be able to restore it later on).

For code in Flash the M3 has a "Flash patching unit" which allows you to specify up to three addresses which shall be read out as 0xBExx (0xBEBE ?) even if other data is stored there. This allows you to set up to 3 breakpoints in Flash.

Interesting for you: The register controlling the debug features in the M3 (named "DEMCR") also has a bit named "MON_STEP":

If you set this bit in interrupt handler #12 then exactly one instruction is executed after returning from the interrupt handler and interrupt #12 is triggered again. The use case for this feature is - of course - single-stepping code!

To stop single-stepping you'll have to clear the MON_STEP bit again...

**Important 1:**

**I don't know** if the MK20DX256VLH7 really has all these features. However because it is a Cortex M4 chip and the M4 should have nearly all features of the M3 these features should be present...

**Important 2:**

Implementing single-stepping and debugging is not done quickly. Assembly language knowledge will be very helpful and you'll need a lot of time...

> From the doc, ...

You will not only need the documentation for the MK20DX256VLH7 from NXP but you'll also need the Cortex M4 documentation from ARM.

(*) Offset 4*12 in the vector table is meant here (which is named "IRQ(-4)" in some ARM documents); not IRQ12.

Answer (score 0):

> yes the ARM emulator/interpreter sounds exactly like what I want. Is there a free one?

qemu is open-source, most of it is GPLv2.  https://wiki.qemu.org/License.  You'd probably need to modify it a lot, because it's designed for use as a stand-alone wrapper for a whole Unix process (qemu-user) or whole machine (qemu-system).

---

I googled, and there's also http://www.unicorn-engine.org/ which is designed to be used as part of a larger program (written in C with bindings for calling from various languages).  It's also GPLv2 (not LGPL), so you can use it if the rest of your code is also Free software.

It's actually based on the CPU-emulation code from QEMU; they stripped out all the device / BIOS emulation stuff to make a flexible library for just emulating CPUs.

Presumably you could configure some memory protections for it and set up the starting machine state, and let it run your function (with a return address that leads to some code that hands control back to your main code?)

Comment: The OP's targeting a microcontroller. It's not going to run QEMU.

Comment: @duskwuff: Unicorn Engine [says it's less than 1 tenth the size of QEMU in code-size and memory consumption](http://www.unicorn-engine.org/docs/beyond_qemu.html).  IDK if that's small enough.  Probably there's a lighter-weight way to sandbox ARM code on an ARM CPU without fully interpreting.  Obviously this isn't a good answer to the main question, but it might be the only one possible if you rule out breakpoints and nearly everything else.  (If ARM has hardware breakpoints, that's an option, though.)

Comment: That's still unlikely to be small enough. QEMU is pretty big, and the OP's microcontroller only has 256 kB of program flash, and 32 kB of RAM. (And they presumably have a lot of other things to do than run an emulator.)

Comment: @duskwuff: Well possibly this will be useful to someone other than the OP.  I posted it mostly as "this is how much it sucks to do exactly what you're asking", and partly because the OP specifically asked about it in comments.  I don't think it's a very good answer, but I'm not sure a better one is possible.  IDK, maybe this should only have been a comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes meh. I'd like to know if this is the best answer there is for emulation. The other option is disassembling the `.obj`, inserting my own code at every branch, load/store, and assembling back to `.obj`.