# ARM - how to execute single assembly instruction (machine code) from within a C function

Tags: c, assembly, arm, elf

Can I execute valid native executable assembly instruction by generating it from within running C code?

```
void execute_single_asm_instruction(char * ptr_asm, int length)
{
    // ptr_asm[] = valid assembly instruction

    execute_asm(ptr, length);
}
```

Is it possible to write `execute_asm`?

This is running on bare-metal ARM i.e. the RTOS is custom and is not Linux, QNX, Windows, etc.

This is related to my previous question:
 [how to single-step code on-target with no jtag, breakpoints, simulator, emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207384/how-to-single-step-code-on-target-with-no-jtag-breakpoints-simulator-emulator)

Comment: You can write instructions to a writable and executable memory (if you have one) and jump there.

Comment: @EugeneSh. what would I google to find the documentation for that?

Comment: Something like... "self-modifying code"

Comment: Sure, a JIT compiler (like LLVM) can do this.  But you don't need a compiler, just an assembler.  Why, though?  Unless you're generating the asm source strings at run-time, it's easier to just have them already assembled to machine-code at build time.  These are called "functions" :P and you call them through function pointers.

Comment: @PeterCordes lol. It's part of my other question. I plan on executing one asm instruction at a time from an existing function.

Comment: Why do you want to store them in text source form, though?  And how are you going to usefully run a branch instruction by itself?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not storing it in text form.

Comment: @PeterCordes good point on the branch . . . I guess I'd have to "preprocess" the code first?

Comment: Oh, `ptr_asm` is a pointer to machine code instructions, not to asm text source.  The variable name and text confused me.  Anyway, the only thing that could stop you from jumping to a block of machine code is memory protection.  But if you have memory protection, then your previous question is already somewhat solved: set up memory protection so the untrusted function can't access memory you don't want it to.  (And statically verify it to make sure it doesn't contain privileged instructions.)

Comment: IDK how you handle branchy asm without decompiling it to C or something and then recompiling.  This just doesn't seem like a viable sandboxing mechanism.

Comment: @PeterCordes [1] C-source to text asm [2] everywhere there's a load/store, insert code to verify mem access is within allowed ranges [3] compile [2] to binary

Comment: @PeterCordes the problem is that if there is a relative branch instruction, I have to modify it to account for my insertions.

Comment: @PeterCordes how do you statically verify the code doesn't contain privileged instruction? He would have to set up not only the memory guards, but also execute it on weaker ring level, so the privileged instruction will not work. It's non-existence can't be proven, it may be hidden too well, or even extracted by bug from the upper level code. (anyway, I agree this is by far the most promising solution, other variants are even lot more trickier to do right)

Comment: @Adrian: Yeah, if you just want to check the load/store addresses, then you only need to disassemble to asm source (with labels for branch targets).  Add instructions to check every access, then re-assemble.  The assembler will re-compute branch displacements for you.  But note that you have to do the checking without destroying any registers that the asm source still needs.  I guess you could save/restore `lr` and insert a `bl` to a function that checks the access and saves/restores flags and all registers it touches.

Comment: About single instruction sandboxing.. after copying it to the sandbox, you will have to check the opcode value, and have triggers for particular instructions (branches/privileged/etc), which will skip execution of the instruction directly, and run your own custom interpreted version written as C function, which will adjust state of the sandbox to simulate the original instruction (within allowed limits). That's what I meant by "not being simple to do 100% correctly".  ... you probably have to create almost full VM either way (with separate state from native machine), even with single ins.step.

Comment: But that's only load/store addresses, not jump targets.  Truly hostile code could jump somewhere outside itself, if it can know what address to find useful instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes if I wanted to limit those, couldn't I also check the jump targets and make sure they're within the stack frame (or within a set of ranges that contain allowable functions to execute)?

Comment: @Ped7g: ARM machine code is harder to hide things in than x86.  In x86 you can jump to the middle of another instruction and it might be a `cli`.  But in ARM, it's either fixed-width or (with Thumb 2) a mix of 16 and 32.  I *think* you're likely to have an easier time finding the right opcodes with static disassembly.

Comment: @Adrian: yes, you could also instrument every indirect jump.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, but if the hostile code is allowed to selfmodify (i.e. build new opcodes dynamically), it may just calculate the privileged one. Again it's getting down about heavy-constrained sandbox/VM which runs each instruction only in very limited way and terminates the code at first discrepancy... rather whitelisting what the untrusted code may do, than trying to blacklist all harmful actions. But that's near the level of providing untrusted party with just some interpreted language inside some simple VM with well guarded API, without any way to actually run ARM instructions at all.

Comment: @Ped7g: you're already checking every load/store address.  Obviously disallow self-modifying, and jumping to places you've written.  But good point about whitelist vs. blacklist.  Also, I agree that interpreting some higher-level language makes *much* more sense than trying to interpret untrusted native machine code.

Comment: @Ped7g you've (kinda) hit the nail on the head. I'm working on micropython which exactly meets the VM requirement. The problem is that our vendors/customers have some "proprietary" code that they don't want to expose. They **could** give it to us in `.py` format and all would be good but that's not obfuscated enough for them.

Comment: @Ped7g unfortunately, uPython doesn't really have a way to load in compiled binaries (except when you're building the VM); it's a feature in progress.

Comment: depends on your business plan and timescale, but proprietary code (in terms of "closed" not providing you with sources ... "proprietary" in terms of copyright, but with sources, is fine by me, as long as usage license is reasonable) is walking zombie thing, may work for you initially, but it's dead since day zero and will collapse at the next opportunity. So if you are designing anything with lifespan above 5 years and have any chance to switch/fire vendors not complying, do that asap. I can't recall to use anything closed source what is older than a decade, gets unusable so quickly...

Comment: @Ped7g this is seed-key function generator (99% of the time). It's not a state secret and yeah, you could always dissemble but it's better than nothing. They don't want your avg hobbyist to gain "root" access to a module.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title and text don't convey the actual question (the OP was looking for an _emulator_), and the OP already has the answer from [another, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207384/how-to-single-step-code-on-target-with-no-jtag-breakpoints-simulator-emulator)

Comment: @jameslarge huh? How is the title not accurate?

Comment: @jameslarge this question asks how to execute a single, assembly instruction

Comment: @jameslarge the other one asks how to get a callback for each assembly executed of a larger function

Comment: If you have control over the code of the RTOS, or at least the ability to run code in EL1 or above, you might be able to get the hardware's debugging capabilities (e.g. "execute one machine instruction in this process context and then trap back into the supervisor", which I'm sure ARM has _somehow_) to help you out here.

Comment: @Adrian, When somebody asks how to execute a single assembly instruction in a C function, they virtually always mean that they want what you can do with the GCC `asm(...)` statement.  That is, to write a C function using a specific machine instruction that is not usually emitted by the C compiler.  You, on the other hand, appear to want to single-step un-trusted machine code in a sandbox environment.  That's a totally different topic.  What you need is an emulator or a VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically impossible to do what you want safely; execute a single assembler instruction.  The issue is 'context' or machine state.  You need to extend the API like this,

```
extern void init_asm_context(void* context);
extern void execute_asm(void* context, char * ptr_asm, int length);

// context; global or declared.
// ptr_asm[] = valid assembly instruction

init_asm_context(&context);
execute_asm(&context, ptr, length);
```

The issue is that any assembler instruction can randomly change registers that the 'C' code depends on.  For this reason, most people make up their own 'virtual machine' and make the machine language easier to decode.  As you have no OS, it is difficult to think of a use case where you are trying to execute off the shelf code and have it work when there is no existing OS.  To do this, you will have constantly context switch with every invocation.  A solution that executes several instructions at a time will perform much quicker as you would not have to save/restore context with **every** instruction.

If you have a security application and performance is critical, I suggest you investigate [proof carrying code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-carrying_code) which is a concept that tries keep performance and make guarantees about memory access.  It is also not as patent encumber as virtual machines (at the moment).

Comment: Makes sense about single asm modifying, for example, `sp`.

Comment: Care to take a crack at my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207384/how-to-single-step-code-on-target-with-no-jtag-breakpoints-simulator-emulator)?

Comment: The OP wants to execute a vendor-supplied seed key algorithm to get access to some other device.  It's only supplied as ARM machine, and the OP wants to trust it as little as possible.